# How can i invoke string var as function?

Tags: python

```
a="string"
b="replace("str","")"
c=a.b
Expected output should be : ing
```

Its pop up error that str is not an attribute.

How can i invoke this function? But using above format only.Please advise me.By using string only

Comment: Try `c = getattr(a, "replace")("l", "")`

Comment: The code in the question is not even valid Python code. Why do you need this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Looks like OP wants to get methods as strings from the client and apply them on objects. Can you clarify what you are expecting?

Comment: The expected output and question doesnt seems valid. Please try to re-frame the question?

Comment: Hello all ! Thanks ! I will be having all the functions in Excel say replace() and I need to fetch that and I have to invoke here

Comment: So make me understand is there is anyway my function is stored and how can I invoke that function with objects in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to change `b` as:

```
b = 'replace("str","")'
```

then you can do this:

```
c = eval(eval('"a."') + eval('b'))
```

Comment: Can we achieve it by using exec()?

Comment: Oh buddy its working !!! thanks a lot . And i have one query in this line please 
 eval('"a."'),why you are giving a single quotes and then double quotes already its mentioning as string only right then why you are giving double and single quotes for a

Comment: anybody please advise me that why here we are using single quotes and then double quotes?

Comment: `>>> eval('"a."')

‘a.’`
here `eval` evaluates whatever there is in double quotes, thus returning a string `a`. the reason i dont want `eval(‘”a.”’)` to return value of variable `a` is that i want the inner two `eval`s to output `a.replace(’str’,’’)`, and the outer eval picks up this and replaces the `a` in `a.replace(’str’, ’’)` with the value of variable `a`, thus returning the value of `“string”.replace(‘str’, ‘’)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(char, my_string):
    result = my_string.replace(char, "")
    return result

final_string = func("str", "string")
print(final_string)
```

result:
    **ing**

I am not sure if it is possible to do what you want only using "string"

Comment: Thanks brother ! But I don't want use replace as manually I need to function that function replace method from a dataframe which is string how can I use then?

Answer (score 0):

Please I know. But at least it isn't as bad as `)b+'.'+a(lave`. Read it backwards.

This uses the `ast` module to parse `"replace('l','')"` into `'replace', ['l', '']`. This will only work on a function call with constant string arguments. It did have to replace the double quotes with singles for this example but it would also work on `'replace("l","")'`.

```
import ast

loan = 'olalt'

a="loan"
b="replace('l','')"

p = ast.parse(b).body[0].value
name = p.func.id
args = [arg.s for arg in p.args]

c=getattr(globals()[a], name)(*args)
c
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace is an in-built function in python. Dont wrap the in-built functions with double quotes, instead use the below lines,

```
a = "string"
b = a.replace("str","")
print(b)
```

The output of b is,

```
ing
```